# Remove duplicates in NSdictionary

Tags: iphone, duplicates, nsdictionary

Is there a way to remove duplicate (key-value) pairs from NSDictionary ?

EDIT:
My description was misleading, I have duplicate pairs e.g.
key1-value1
key1-value1
key2-value2
key1-value1
etc..

Comment: how can you have duplicates in a dictionary? according to Apple documentation, duplicates are automatically removed when you add another key of the same name: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reversing key-value is not good idea because not all values can be keys.
 You can do it with:

// dict is original dictionary, newDict new dictionary withot duplicates.

```
NSMutableDictionary * newDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:[dict count]];
for(id item in [dict allValues]){
    NSArray * keys = [dict allKeysForObject:item];
    [newDict setObject:item forKey:[keys objectAtIndex:0]];
}
```

yuo can also use lastObject instead of objectAtIndex:0 to leave other key for dup objects

Answer (score 1):

One way is to put the key/value pairs into a dictionary by value/key and then converting that back to key/value.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a built-in method.

If you iterate over the values, allKeysForObject: will give you an array of keys for each value and if you have more more than one key, that value has duplicates.