# Get the dictionary which is the latest in array iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, nsarray

I have array contains many dictionary as below:

```
Array =  {
        buyerID = 00000000000w;
        time = 1404919942804;
        id = 0000000000Aa;
    },
        {
        buyerID = 00000000000Z;
        time = 1404670971396;
        id = 0000000000Aa;
    },
        {
        buyerID = 00000000000Z;
        time = 1406531476764;
        id = 0000000000Ab;
    },
        {
        buyerID = 00000000000w;
        time = 1406531476213;
        id = 0000000000Aa;
    },
```

The expect result is:

```
LastArray =  {
        buyerID = 00000000000w;
        time = 1404919942804;
        id = 0000000000Aa;
    },
        {
        buyerID = 00000000000Z;
        time = 1404670971396;
        id = 0000000000Aa;
    },
        {
        buyerID = 00000000000Z;
        time = 1406531476764;
        id = 0000000000Ab;
    },
```

That means I want to remove the last object because the BuyerID and ID are the same as the first item. How can i do that? Please give me some advice. Thanks so much.

Comment: There is no magic built in way to do this.  You will have to make an algorithm for it.  One idea is to make a hash of the buyerID and id together and make a separate NSDictionary.  If the hash exists as a key in the dictionary, then you can check the value and update it to the later of the two times.  If it doesn't, then simply add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove duplicates try this -

```
NSMutableArray *objectsToRemove =   [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i=0; i<mutableArray.count; i++) {
    for (int j=i+1; j<mutableArray.count; j++) {
        if ([[[mutableArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"buyerID"] isEqualToString:[[mutableArray objectAtIndex:j]valueForKey:@"buyerID"]] && [[[mutableArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"id"] isEqualToString:[[mutableArray objectAtIndex:j]valueForKey:@"id"]]) {
            [objectsToRemove addObject:[mutableArray objectAtIndex:j]];
        }
    }
}

[mutableArray removeObjectsInArray:objectsToRemove];
NSLog(@"AFTER :: %@",mutableArray);
```

Replace mutableArray by your array.

Comment: I want to compare 2 keys in dictionary, if they are exist, then remove it.

Comment: Check Edited answer.. May this help you.

Answer (score 0):

If the Array(data) is fixed, then simply `removeAtObject` is enough, `[myArray removeObjectAtIndex:myArray.count-1];`OR `[myArray removeLastObject];`

If you want to remove duplicates, then [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462481/remove-duplicates-in-nsdictionary)

Comment: Thanks. but i need to compare 2 keys : BuyerID and id. How can i do that? Can you example code? Thanks much

Comment: @Kumar KL, I think it will be better to call `[myArray removeLastObject];`

Comment: Iterate the array and get the Dictionaries and compare accordingly

Answer (score 0):

'containsObject' is your friend here. It can check for complex object types within an array. So as part of your code that is adding the objects to the mutable array, you can add a filter to stop duplicates...

```
NSMutableArray *cleanArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
if (![cleanArray containsObject:dictionaryToAdd]) {
   [cleanArray addObject:dictionaryToAdd];
}
```

So concentrate at the place where the array is being populated by these objects and add the filter code above to ensure only unique objects are added. NSSet might help also.